# Define Class Method Names Based On Other Types Typescript

Tags: typescript

Say I have a bunch of classes that do similar things (for this instance add to a set
) but what they do is very different. Writing it out by hand results in code like this:

```
class Foo {
    fooSet: Set<string> = new Set()
    addFoo(foo: string) {
        this.fooSet.add(foo)
    }
    delFoo(foo: string) {
        this.fooSet.delete(foo)
    }
    // Foo code
}

class Bar{
    barSet: Set<string> = new Set()
    addBar(bar: string) {
        this.barSet.add(bar)
    }
    delBar(bar: string) {
        this.barSet.delete(bar)
    }
    // Bar code
}
```

Thats a lot of useless work. Instead, I want to make a function `namedSet(name: string)` that returns a class with all those methods already in there. A first try of mine was:

```
export const NamedSet = <N extends string>(name: N) => {
    const lowerName = name.toLowerCase() as Lowercase<N>;
    const capitalName = name[0].toUpperCase() + name.substring(1) as Capitalize<N>;


    return class  {
        private readonly [`${lowerName}Set`]: Set<string> = new Set();

        [`add${capitalName}`](str: string): void {
            this[`${lowerName}Set`].add(str);
        }

        [`del${capitalName}`](str: string): void {
            this[`${lowerName}Set`].delete(str);
        }
    }
}
```

However this fails because `A computed property name in a class property declaration must have a simple literal type or a 'unique symbol' type.` (the set initalizer) and `Type '`${Lowercase}Set`' cannot be used to index type 'this'.` (inside the methods) The second error I believe would be fixed if the class knew that it had `${Lowercase<N>}Set`. However, TS does not let me define it the normal JS way. Is this possible, and if so how?

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/Nnagvw) meet your needs?  Class and interface declarations require statically known keys, and yours are essentially dynamic.  You can make a class declaration with a string index signature and then *assert* that it has the shape you want, but it's a bit tedious and the compiler isn't really type checking it for you much.  Still, it works how you want more or less from the outside.  Let me know if you want me to write up an answer or if I'm missing something about the question.

Comment: looks like it works from a quick look

Comment: Take a longer look and get back to me; I don't want to spend a lot of time writing up an answer (my answers tend to be longwinded^H^H^H^H^H^H thorough) if it doesn't actually meet your needs.

Comment: Everything works, if you want to write a long answer go ahead 

Comment: Okay, I'll write up an answer when I get a chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem you're running into is that [interface](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#interfaces) and [class](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html) declarations in TypeScript are required to have *statically known key names*; that is, their specific types need to be known to the compiler at compile time.  *Dynamic keys* are rejected.  (Note that [index signatures](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures) are not what I mean by "dynamic keys" here.  A `string` index signature means that all values of the specific type `string` are acceptable keys. The type `string` is not generic.)  So what can we do?

Well, we can definitely represent types with dynamic key types in the language; they just can't be interface or class declarations.  The main way to have a dynamic key is to use a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type alias of a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) where the key is generic.  Something of the form `type Foo<K extends string> = {[P in K]: XXX}`, for example.  The canonical example of this is [the `Record<K, V>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeystype), which represents a type with keys of type `K` and values of type `V`.

By [intersecting](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) together object types of the form `Record<K, V>` for some `K` and `V`, we can build up a representation of whatever dynamic type you want.  In your case, let's describe the desired shape of an instance of the `NamedSet<N>` class:

```
type NamedSet<N extends string> = 
  Record<`${Lowercase<N>}Set`, Set<string>> &
  Record<`add${Capitalize<N>}`, (str: string) => void> &
  Record<`del${Capitalize<N>}`, (str: string) => void>
```

So we have an object which has:

- a property with a key of type `` `${Lowercase<N>}Set` `` whose value is of type `Set<string>`, **and**
- a property with a key of type `` `add${Capitalize<N>}` `` whose value is of type `(str: string) => void`, **and**
- a property with a key of type `` `del${Capitalize<N>}` `` whose value is of type `(str: string) => void`.

So if that's the type of instances of `NamedSet<N>`, what's the type of the *constructor*?  That would be a [construct signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#construct-signatures) like this:

```
type NamedSetConstructor<N extends string> = new () => NamedSet<N>;
```

So a value of type `NamedSetConstructor<N>` is a class constructor that takes no arguments when you call `new` on it, and produces an instance of type `NamedSet<N>`.  That means we want your `NamedSet()` function to return a value of type `NamedSetConstructor<N>`.

---

Unfortunately, as said above, the compiler will never be able to verify that any particular `class` declaration is assignable to `NamedSetConstructor<N>`.  Instead, we'll need to write some `class` declaration that has the desired *runtime* behavior, give it a weak enough type so that the compiler accepts it, and then just [assert](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) that it's of type `NamedSetConstructor<N>`.  That means the implementation of `NamedSet()` will not be particularly type safe; we need to be careful.  But at least *callers* of `NamedSet()` won't have a problem.  Here goes:

```
const NamedSet = <N extends string>(name: N) => {
  const lowerName = name.toLowerCase()
  const capitalName = name[0].toUpperCase() + name.substring(1)

  return class {
    [k: string]: any;
    constructor() {
      this[`${lowerName}Set`] = new Set<string>() as any;
    }
    [`add${capitalName}`](str: string): void {
      this[`${lowerName}Set`].add(str);
    }

    [`del${capitalName}`](str: string): void {
      this[`${lowerName}Set`].delete(str);
    }
  } as NamedSetConstructor<N>
}
```

Note that the class expression has a string index signature of value type `any`, which is very loosely typed.  And even so I need to assign `` this[`${lowerName}Set`] `` with another assertion to avoid errors.  And at the end we assert the whole thing as `NamedSetConstructor<N>`.

---

So, does it work?

```
class Foo extends NamedSet("foo") { }
const foo = new Foo();
foo.addFoo("abc");
foo.addFoo("def");
foo.delFoo("abc");
console.log(Array.from(foo.fooSet)) // ["def"]    

class Bar extends NamedSet("bar") { }
const bar = new Bar();
bar.addBar("ghi");
bar.addBar("jkl");
bar.delBar("jkl");
console.log(Array.from(bar.barSet)) // ["ghi"]
```

Looks good.  The compiler recognizes that `foo` has methods `addFoo`, `delFoo`, and a `fooSet` property, and that `bar` has methods `addBar`, `delBar`, and a `barSet` property, and they all behave as desired at runtime.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-mF1Ri8v9fuMBbTJu262W7HyMLCWACFySoVN4WCTgdwBQNgygAAxIQhERTp-1BQD2AAIh6RCMPicZW15ClsKQissQQoR5TOYjV2ccjMLgJ0BFwqjEJo5A6Iw3IemYzhqP3DiGKYr9eSEHx7QFN0AEEqCoOAQDFHoqCEBB2Go4jdFiFo2gmTiIG4tYAVJINSHIAAhOAqGQ5FKTBDBMKdCzcLGXZSWTKAHMs0ioHM9Mvw8tifMw+hXh4-yHkCjCACt5h8UKLLFfcIui2LhKVUTxKEKSZLkhSlJU-yPI0rTJgw4KaAwgyASAA)