# Is it possible to create a type definition for dynamically generated class methods in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, web-component, custom-element

Is there a way to create a type definition for class method names that are dynamically generated and follow a naming format like `{name}Ref`? Basically, I'm wondering if something like this is possible:

```ts
export declare class BaseElement extends HTMLElement {
  // ... other type definitions ...
  [`${Lowercase<string>}Ref`](): HTMLElement | null {} // <-- is something like this possible?
}
```

**Context:**

I'm building a custom element base class that will find child elements with the attribute `:ref="name"` and dynamically create a new method on the base class that will return a reference to the node the attribute was defined on and follows the naming format: `{name}Ref`.

The code is completely functional at this point, but I'm having a problem with correctly defining types for it.

Here's an abridged version of the base class:

```js
class BaseElement extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    let node;
    const iterator = document.createNodeIterator(this, NodeFilter.SHOW_ELEMENT);
    while ((node = iterator.nextNode())) {
      if (!node) return;
      if (node instanceof HTMLElement) {
        for (const attr of node.attributes) {
          if (attr.name === ':ref') {
            this.#generateRefMethod(attr);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  #generateRefMethod(attr) {
    const elem = attr.ownerElement;
    if (elem && elem instanceof HTMLElement) {
      const refName = `${attr.value}Ref`;
      // Attach getter method to BaseElement
      this[refName] = () => elem;
      // Remove `:ref` attribute from elem since it's 
      // a non-standard HTML attribute
      elem.removeAttributeNode(attr);
    }
  }
}
```

**The problem:**

When I consume/use this in a typescript file I get an error saying the method does not exist on the child class.

```ts
import {BaseElement} from './BaseElement.js';
class Child extends BaseElement {   
  constructor() {
    super();
    const ref = this.someRef?.(); // Error: Property 'someRef' does not exist on type 'Child'.
    if (ref) {
      ref.textContent = "some text";
    }
  }
}
```

**Current solution:**

I figured out I can use the `declare` keyword to resolve this problem, but this can get a bit verbose/annoying to declare every single ref on every single class that extends BaseElement.

```ts
class Child extends BaseElement {
  declare someRef: () => HTMLElement | null;    
  constructor() {
    super();
    const ref = this.someRef?.(); // No more error!
    if (ref) {
      ref.textContent = "some text";
    }
  }
}
```

It would be great if the BaseElement class could be responsible for defining the method types instead of the child class, thus we circle back to the question above, is something like this is possible?

```ts
export declare class BaseElement extends HTMLElement {
  // ... other type definitions ...
  [`${Lowercase<string>}Ref`](): HTMLElement | null {} // <-- is something like this possible?
}
```

**Extra notes:**

Here's a slight variant of the minimal reproduction in Stackblitz showing a [counter button example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-nzhmek?file=index.ts).

The BaseElement class is defined in a javascript file and then I've handwritten my types in a `.d.ts` file, so if answers could be catered to that reality that would be appreciated.

I also found [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71820154/define-class-method-names-based-on-other-types-typescript) that seems somewhat related and discusses a solution for defining method name types that follow a pattern of `{dynamicString}Postfix`, but I really struggled to translate the solution of that problem to what I'm working on.

Comment: How do you know `this.someRef` is safe to call?

Comment: Where does `attr` come from in the abridged version of your base class and what is its type?  Wouldn't `generateRef()` be a bad name since it isn't of the right type but matches the pattern for naming?  It would be very helpful to have a [mre] that we can just play with in our own IDEs without having to resolve unrelated problems.  Could you [edit] to provide one?

Comment: Sorry @kelsny could clarify your question a bit? Are you asking how I would safely handle a call to `this.someRef()` or how I know that `this.someRef` has been correctly attached to the BaseElement class (or maybe something else entirely)?

Comment: Given what's here I'd think of doing something like [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/m3VbqN) shows, but I made a lot of assumptions so I really hope you can provide a nice [mre].

Comment: @jcalz `attr` comes from creating a [NodeIterator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeIterator) (`document.createNodeIterator`) with the custom element as the root and then processing each node in the DOM tree and making a call to the [`Element.attributes` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/attributes). Also ooh shoot, great catch on the `generateRef` naming! I hadn't thought of that. Also yes, I'd be more than happy to provide a minimal reproduction and then update my original post. I'll do so now.

Comment: @jcalz okay here's a [small reproduction](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-nzhmek?file=index.ts) (I also edited the post above)! I made a small counter button example in StackBlitz so that the code can be seen in action a bit more, but please let me know if I can adjust the reproduction in some way to be more helpful!

Comment: I’ll take a look when I get to a real computer, but in general a [mre] should be included as plaintext in the question itself and not only as an external link.  The stackblitz link is a nice supplement but it doesn’t suffice since we can’t require people navigate away to see it.

Comment: You're doing a lot of ignoring of possible `null`s and `undefined`s and the only reason you don't get errors is because you're not using `--strict`.  Could you clear that up?  And does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wX1bLN) meet your needs? It's pretty similar to my last suggestion, so I hope you can review it and tell me if it addresses your question enough for me to write up as an actual answer (and then delete these comments) or if I'm missing something.

Comment: Why don't you just `class Base{ $refs: Record<string, HTMLElement> }` ?

Comment: Optionally as `$refs = new Proxy({}, { get: (...a) => this.getRef(...a) })` if yo need some logic

Comment: @jcalz I had a quick moment to try out the approach you linked to and it worked perfectly! Please feel free to give a full write-up. Also apologies, somehow I missed the first time you linked to the MRE docs and just assumed the TS link you sent meant I should link to an external reproduction  I'm going to be out and about the rest of the day but I'll make sure to give everything a proper update once I'm back home.

Comment: @Dimava ooh interesting! I hadn't thought about adding all the refs to an object attached to the base class. That might end up being a bit cleaner than what I'm trying to do here so I'll give that a try, thank you! However, since this question is primarily focused on how to create typing for dynamically created class methods with a naming pattern, I think the suggestion from jcalz has correctly answered my original question.

Comment: @jcalz okay I updated the original post to add a proper MRE and do my best to account for possible nulls/undefined. Please let me know if there's any I missed, however!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can indeed give a class or an interface a [template string pattern index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-4.html#symbol-and-template-string-pattern-index-signatures), like this:

```
declare class BaseElement extends HTMLElement {
    [x: `${Lowercase<string>}Ref`]: (() => HTMLElement | null) | undefined
}
```

which means that any property of `BaseElement` whose key is a lowercase string followed by `"Ref"` is either a no-arg function returning `HTMLElement | null` or it is `undefined`.  Only strings matching `` `${Lowercase<string>}Ref` `` are given that type:

```
this.ABCRef // error
this.abcRef // okay
this.abcDef // error
```

Only `this.abcRef` is recognized because it's of the right form, whereas `this.ABCRef` fails because `ABC` isn't lowercase, and `abcDef` fails because it doesn't end in `Ref`.

And note that I added that `undefined` possibility in the value type to remind you to check that some random method exists before calling it:

```
class Something extends BaseElement {
    foo() {
        const r = this.abcdeRef?.();
        // optional chaining ->^^
        // const r: HTMLElement | null | undefined
    }
}
```

That uses [the optional chaining operator (`?.`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) to call `this.abcdeRef` if and only if it is present, and the result `r` is either `HTMLElement | null` or `undefined`.

Checking for `null` and `undefined` is recommended, but if you don't want that to be forced to do such checks, you can remove `undefined` from the index signature value (and make sure [`--noUncheckedIndexedAccess`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#checked-indexed-accesses---nouncheckedindexedaccess) is disabled).  And if you do that, don't be surprised if you hit runtime errors.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEkoGdnwEIpAUQiAtiAHYAu8IAHiccGgBIAqAsgDK4HFkDeAUPP-ADaFAFzwABgBIuLAPYB3EDDBYAPMhIwAlkQDmAPgC+AJRAAzcQF0xAChsBKeAF598Rq3aFS8AD7wiAK4QEI5+AUSgZjogwDyGPAlIqPAAyrKEJAAWOrrkVDRomMg4eF7cfAJmsrIO8LwCDYiyRBrwMM7wWVrIAHRQAEZgoKZmAPw9DgDcFY3wAPRz8LIADiRazVAQiJlQOjnwALT6AHrHM40LTS1kMGLubKWcvv5BW2ER5tGx5w1dvQCC6AAwiN5oslDBZDAfgI-n1BqDLrIANZQACeMP4cIGYAAIuYweQYJDoQ14vEeEk0EDZOFqDB0AESCRmnlqBFClhPE9eOcwM0iOBqMAgZsIP0oGBkQ4xAA3WRaYB1TFXVr9JksogdOEARwCSjRKRAeDALJgNgA5Ormc0LfZprN+NbNeMoMBgNhZZwWN12UpLZAtFKLQAaTrZXo6MBwMr284UhpRmNPJzwWouZWO1U3AmpuH8ukjcZTFVaMxpuBmRz1LMCfnXJp0jrLWDFACSpBslZ61CoNNIT1Go3gACIR3HawJu72SP32WRUylNDkbAXvABqeAARgnjviZOmFLAAQ06W5pF6kWiAdpA5gB2dtrDNLpSkZNqIcaAA)

Comment: Wow. Learned something new today. Didn't know you could do `x.foo?.()`